# Вывод текста с переносом слов

Tags: android, canvas

Как, используя `Canvas` в *Android*, вписать текст в определенную область?

Есть ли готовые решения?

К примеру, есть область и длинное предложение, необходимо вписать это предложение в эту область с переносами слов.

Есть ли возможность использовать *html*-верстку при выводе?

К примеру, использовать тэги - `<b>`, `<i>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ответ.

```
    TextPaint textPaint=new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    textPaint.setTextSize(90);
    Spanned myString = Html.fromHtml("This <b>is</b> my text that must fit to a rectangle");
    StaticLayout sl = new StaticLayout(myString.subSequence(0,myString.length()), textPaint, (int)rect.width(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, 1, false);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(rect.left, rect.top);
    sl.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот использую процедуру, определяет максимальный размер текста который можно вписать в заданный прямоугольник.

```
public static int[] determineMaxTextSizeWithBounds(String str, Rect mBounds) {
        if (str.length() == 0) {
            str = " ";
        }
        int size = (int) (mBounds.width() / str.length());
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setTextSize(size);

        // to do optimal need find when to more, and do step back.
        while (paint.measureText(str) < mBounds.width()) {
            paint.setTextSize(++size);
        }

        while (paint.measureText(str) > mBounds.width()) {
            // size--;
            paint.setTextSize(--size);
        }               

        // проверка на высоту
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds("A", 0, 1, bounds);

        while (bounds.height() > mBounds.height()) {
            paint.setTextSize(--size);
            paint.getTextBounds("A", 0, 1, bounds);
        }

        return new int[] { size, (int) paint.measureText(str), bounds.height() };
    }
```

возвращает массив - размер текста + реально полученные границы (они нужны чтобы получившийся текст центрировать).